# Removing inherited ASP.NET Core appsettings

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I have the following setup in my Startup:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
}
```

I know I can override the effective settings for a given environment by adding a matching JSON structure with different values and omitting those I want to inherit, e.g. appsettings.Development.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
}
```

But can I *remove* an entry or a section except by overriding each value property with an empty value?

-S

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) documentation, settings are loaded from both files and if a setting is specified in both on them, than the one in the latter, i.e. `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json` in your setup, will override the first one.

So, if a setting is specified in the `appsettings.json` file and you want to remove it when running in the *Development* environment, you will need to explicitly set that accordingly ("", {}, etc. depending on the setting) in the `appsettings.Development.json` file.

However, such setup may suggest your setting should not lie in the generic `appsettings.json` file, but in the specific environments configuration settings file directly.
This way, it might be easier to write your settings.

Comment: It's not legal to assign `null` (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=basicconfiguration#values)

Comment: @DavidGardiner you are right. I just updated based on your feedback, thanks.

Comment: This answer does not really provide definitive solution. For example, if one of my config keys is a TimeSpan, and I configure some value for it in `appsettings.json`, how can I unset it in `appsettings.Development.json`? If I set it to `"configKey": ""`, I will get an exception, because an empty string is not assignable to a `TimeSpan`.